# Where to use One way message exchange in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I'm thinking of what should be practical example of using WCF one way message exchange, 
since I'm concerned about success or failure of any operation which I send to WCF service 
and in one way message exchange - WCF service does not report success or failure of operation.

Comment: Erm...it sounds like you figured out the answer yourself. One-way messages are for "fire and forget" operation, where the success and failure of the operation is not important. For example, logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your binding is **MSMQ**, you must use one-way operations.

> *All service operations must be one-way because the default queued binding in WCF does not support duplex communication using queues*  -  [Queuing in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048(v=vs.110).aspx)

Plus, callbacks to a possible client regardless of protocol should be one-way in case the client has snuffed it.